# jQuery each() method does not working for appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, each

i'm trying to append `tr` with it's inner tags to my table. this function happens when document is ready. Then with a `.each()` method, i'm trying to add some classes to appended `tr` elements. but it seems to jQuery does not recognize my appended html content. what should i do to solve my problem? Thank you all.

The html content that i want to append them:

```js
let appndContent = '<tr class="RoomTableTr" style="background-color: red;">\n' +
  '<td class="RoomTableTd v2 borderedTd">\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays costInTable"></p>\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays">ریال</p>\n' +
  '</td>\n' +
  '<td class="RoomTableTd v2 borderedTd">\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays costInTable"></p>\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays">ریال</p>\n' +
  '</td>\n' +
  '<td class="RoomTableTd v2 borderedTd">\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays costInTable"></p>\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays">ریال</p>\n' +
  '</td>\n' +
  '<td class="RoomTableTd v2 borderedTd">\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays costInTable"></p>\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays">ریال</p>\n' +
  '</td>\n' +
  '<td class="RoomTableTd v2 borderedTd">\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays costInTable"></p>\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays">ریال</p>\n' +
  '</td>\n' +
  '<td class="RoomTableTd v2 borderedTd">\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays costInTable"></p>\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays">ریال</p>\n' +
  '</td>\n' +
  '<td class="RoomTableTd v2">\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays costInTable"></p>\n' +
    '<p class="costPerDays">ریال</p>\n' +
  '</td>\n' +
'</tr>';

$('.DepartureDate').each(function() {
  let day = parseInt($(this).val().substring(8, 10)),
    month = parseInt($(this).val().substring(5, 7)),
    year = parseInt($(this).val().substring(0, 4)),
    DayOfWeek = new persianDate();
  DayOfWeek.date(day);
  DayOfWeek.month(month);
  DayOfWeek.year(year);
  let TheDay = DayOfWeek.format('dddd');

  let CostInf = $(this).parent().parent().find('.CostInf').val();
  switch (TheDay) {
    case 'شنبه':
      $(".RoomTableTr td:nth-child(1) .costInTable").empty().append(CostInf).parent().addClass('DepartureDateMark');
      break;
    case 'یکشنبه':
      $(".RoomTableTr td:nth-child(2) .costInTable").empty().append(CostInf).parent().addClass('DepartureDateMark');
      break;
    case 'دوشنبه':
      $(".RoomTableTr td:nth-child(3) .costInTable").empty().append(CostInf).parent().addClass('DepartureDateMark');
      break;
    case 'سه شنبه':
      $(".RoomTableTr td:nth-child(4) .costInTable").empty().append(CostInf).parent().addClass('DepartureDateMark');
      break;
    case 'چهار شنبه':
      $(".RoomTableTr td:nth-child(5) .costInTable").empty().append(CostInf).parent().addClass('DepartureDateMark');
      break;
    case 'پنج‌شنبه':
      $(".RoomTableTr td:nth-child(6) .costInTable").empty().append(CostInf).parent().addClass('DepartureDateMark');
      break;
    case 'جمعه':
      $(".RoomTableTr td:nth-child(7) .costInTable").empty().append(CostInf).parent().addClass('DepartureDateMark');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  let lastDay = $(this).parent().find('.DepartureDateMark').last();
  lastDay.attr('data-lastDay', true);
  lastDay.addClass('data-lastDay');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and code to show a [mcve]

Comment: When and where is `appndContent` actually appended to the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

you should append your variable "appndContent" before using it in switch-case(e.g. before each function). if you append that after switch-case or not appended yet then this query will not work.